# bash command line arithmetic echo $((x-y)) how to divide result by z?

Tags: bash, math

I'm trying to figure out a way to take the result of a basic equation and divide by another integer. So in in simple form it looks like;
A-B = C and then divide C by D

I understand the first part of the equation is echo $((A-B)) but how do I get that result divided by D?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I've tried "echo $((2147483633-807279114))/5184000))" but gotten errors. First time trying advanced arithmetic in Linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using shell

This (taken from the comments) fails because the parentheses are unbalanced:

```
$ echo $((2147483633-807279114))/5184000))
```

Try instead:

```
$ echo $(( (2147483633-807279114)/5184000 ))
258
```

The above returns an integer because the shell only does integer arithmetic.

#### Using `bc`

If you want accurate floating-point numbers, the standard tool to use is `bc`:

```
$ echo '(2147483633-807279114)/5184000' | bc -l
258.52710628858024691358
```

#### Using `python`

Python supports both integer and floating point arithmetic:

```
$ python -c 'print (2147483633-807279114)//5184000'
258
$ python -c 'print (2147483633-807279114)/5184000.0'
258.527106289
```

Python, with its numpy extension, is an excellent tool even if your needs extend to complex scientific calculations.

#### Using `awk`

`awk`, a standard unix tool, supports floating-point math:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print (2147483633-807279114)/5184000;quit}'
258.527
```

Comment: "$ echo $(( (2147483633-807279114)/5184000 ))
258" Was exactly what I needed. thanks so much for the replies!

Answer (score 3):

You can do calculations inside `$((  ))`

If you want to calculate `(A-B)/C`, you can put that inside `$((  ))`:

```
echo $(( (A-B)/C ))
```

Note that the result will be truncated towards zero, because bash does not support decimals.

Remember to make sure that you have `$((` before the expression and `))` after, and that all the parentheses inside match up.

Answer (score 0):

```
dc <<< "$A $B - $D / p"
```

Note 1: p prints the final result

Note 2: With dc you need to first enter the numbers and then operation